# Accordion is not expanding div

Tags: accordion

Browser: ie11 (My company requires this).

Once expanded, it overflows the div and the footer.

I need it to extend the div behind it so it always fits.

Currently, the div behind has these attributes:

```
 height:600px;
width:650px;
background-color:white;
margin-left:200px;
margin-top:-520px;
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
border-radius:50px 10px 50px 10px;
border:solid;
border-width: 5 5px;
border-color: #fcf17a;
box-shadow:5px 5px 12px black;
font-size: 12px;
```

I am also using the Vallenato accordion as I'm not too good with JS myself.
Found here:
http://www.switchroyale.com/vallenato/

Image of accordion here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIWf9.png

Thanks for your time.

Comment: change the height min-height:600px;

Comment: @generalgmt then there is a huge space the the bottom of the page while the accordion is collapsed.

Comment: Then, use the relative height of the accordion as the min-height of the div.